# How could I network during my Phd?

Tags: phd, postdocs, networking

I am thinking a bit ahead of time and I would like to do some networking with some groups in my research field, for probably a future postdoc opportunity with them after my PhD. However I am afraid my supervisor prevents me to do that, she doesn't seem very happy with the idea of me doing some research stays somewhere else, or even going to conferences, and most likely she would connect me with anyone during and after my PhD, so how could I do some networking ??

Comment: You should ignore your supervisor, assuming you've discussed this with your supervisor and they remain dismissive

Comment: "she doesn't seem very happy with the idea of me [...] going to conferences" Major red flag. Is the lab underfunded?

Comment: well as PhD students we could use some little budget (with approval of the supervisor) to go to conferences and courses, however she considers that as a major distraction from my work

Comment: @user2768, ignoring your supervisor sounds like particularly  bad advice. How does that get you anywhere?

Comment: Perhaps your supervisor is correct and that you don't, in fact, need any major distractions now. I can't judge the case, of course, but at least consider that she has some knowledge and judgement here and isn't just trying to thwart you.

Comment: @Buffy The OP seems to be exasperated with their supervisor, seemingly after many attempts to move forward. Yet, their supervisor is failing to provide support. This is a "major red flag," as noted by Roland. I have a general tendency to assume supervisors are operating in the best interests of their students, but the scenario described suggests that this particular supervisor is not. Unfortunately, supervisors don't always give the best advice (nor can they be expected too) and sometimes a student must make the best of a situation.

Comment: @user2768, Yes, I understand that. But going against the express wishes of a supervisor is _always_ sub optimal. If you can't get along, find a different supervisor with different attitudes. Even changing institutions if necessary. But if you have to stay, the supervisor has power that you have no way to counter effectively. It isn't about fairness or justice at that point. It is about safety and the ability to finish your degree successfully.  I think it is wrong to give advice here that puts the OP, but not yourself, at risk. First, Do No Harm.

Comment: @Buffy Usually I'd agree, but the OP is "thinking a bit ahead of time" with the goal of finding "a future postdoc opportunity," which suggests the OP is nearing completion and needs to act. (I strongly disagree that I shouldn't offer advice that has a risk.)

Comment: We could probably give you a bit more pointed answers if you provide a bit more detail: which field are you working in (some fields conferences are primary publishing venues, some other ones, not much more than fun events), when did you start your PhD and how long do you still have left, did you already get your first publication out there? Telling you to focus on your research with no distractions might actually be a valid strategy in the beginning of your PhD, while focusing on collaborations and networking gets more important once you establish your research a bit around mid-PhD.

Answer (score 4):

I have a few suggestions.

- Check out LinkedIn and join groups based on your field of interest. Simply having a profile and stating your field of study will help people find you. Comment on articles, or even write posts, because it will help people see your name. Don't be scared to message people you don't know.
- If you have the money, let your supervisor know you're taking a week or whatever off and go to the conference yourself.
- If you don't like the last point, look up speakers at conferences and point out ones to your supervisor that would be applicable and helpful for your studies. Remind her that it may bring you more insight or better ideas for your own work. Let her know that you can work on your studies during non-conference hours if necessary.
- Watch for alumni events within your own faculty. If there are none, ask other professors or the department head if they know of any talks coming up that may be of interest. Just because you have a supervisor doesn't mean you can't talk to other professors.

Answer (score 1):

I think that ignoring or going around your advisor/supervisor is a very dangerous practice. It could leave you without a degree or, even with a degree, without good recommending letters.

But if you have to give up face to face networking, there is no reason in today's world that you can't correspond with other professionals on common interests. All you need is an email address. If you also have a web site with valuable resources for others, then others can find you as well.

International collaboration is a very common thing these days, and while occasional face to face meetings is desirable they aren't, strictly speaking, necessary.